# Reference ObjectDataSource DataObjectType from ObjectDataSource.OnUpdating Event

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, objectdatasource

I have an `ObjectDataSource` which uses a `DataObjectType` (Name). In this case `EmpRow` to pass update and insert parameters instead of passing individual parameters.

The ODS is used by the `FormView` which has two Multi Select `ListBox` controls. Because the `ListBox` controls will only pass one selected item, I need to properly add all selected values to the `DataObject` before the datasource updates.

So in the `ObjectDataSource.OnUpdating` event I want to iterate the selected items and adjust the proper values in the `DataObject` that is passed to the dataource update method.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to get a reference to the dataobject. It looks like to only way to it would be through the `OrderedDictionary`? Is that Right? Some how I need to reference the `EmpRow` object and update a couple of property values?

Any Ideas?

```
protected void dsDetail_Updating(object sender,      
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
{

    OrderedDictionary od = (OrderedDictionary) e.InputParameters;
    IDictionaryEnumerator castRowEnum = (IDictionaryEnumerator)od.GetEnumerator();

    //Now I somehow want to create an EmpRow object from the 
    //passed DataObjectType of the datasource

    FormView fv = (FormView)FormView1;
    ListBox lstLanguages = (ListBox)fv.Row.FindControl("lstSpokenLanguages");
    ListBox lstSECPSTypes = (ListBox)fv.Row.FindControl("lstSECPSTypes");

    string strSpokenLanguages = "";
    string strSECPSTypes = "";

    foreach (ListItem item in lstLanguages.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            strSpokenLanguages += item.Value + ",";
        }
    }
    strSpokenLanguages = strSpokenLanguages.Substring(0,                               
                                       (strSpokenLanguages.Length - 1));


    foreach (ListItem item in lstSECPSTypes.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            strSECPSTypes += item.Value + ",";
        }
    }
    strSECPSTypes = strSECPSTypes.Substring(0, (strSECPSTypes.Length - 1));

    //now i need to assign these values to the proper data object properties
    //EmpRow.cSECPSTypes = strSECPSTypes;
    //EmpRow.cSpokenLanguages = strSpokenLanguages;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. EmpRow empRow = (EmpRow) e.InputParameters[0];

Answer (score 1):

I have reached a solution which is to do:

```
EmpRow empRow = (EmpRow) e.InputParameters[0];
```